# How to print in drop-down list in jxs?

Tags: reactjs

How to print in drop-down list in jxs? Actually I'm having drop-down list and by this code i'm getting all the data in one single row  while clicking on it but  I want it in list. Can anyone help me out for this?

My code:

```
comboClick () {
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://api.eventsacross-stage.railsfactory.com/api/";
    var input = this.state.search_event;
    let self = this;
    let location = [];
    let cityArray = [];
    axios.get(apiBaseUrl+'v1/events/?on_dashboard=false'+input)
    .then(function (response) {
       let events = response.data.events;
       for(var i = 0; i < response.data.events_count; i++) {
         var obj = response.data.events[i];
         location.push(obj.locations[0].city);
       }
       let cityUnique = _.uniq(location, 'city');
       cityArray.push(cityUnique);
       self.setState({cityArray: cityArray});
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });console.log("cityArray",cityArray);
   }
```

jsx part:

```
render() {
    var cityFilter = [this.state.cityArray ? this.state.cityArray[0] : null];
    {console.log("cityFilter",cityFilter)}
    return (...
<div className="dropdown text-center">
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        style={{width: "50%"}}
                        onClick={this.comboClick.bind(this)}>
                          Place
                          <span className="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                        {cityFilter.map(function(city, index){
                          return <li className="text-center" key={ index }>{city}</li>;
                        })}
                      </ul>

                    </div>

...}
```

Comment: seems like your cityFilter will only contain one element

Comment: cityFilter is an array. it is holding values.